# Asymptotic propagation of error

Tags: probability, statistics, upper-lower-bounds, error-propagation

Let $\tilde{s}_n$ and $\tilde{p}_n$ be estimators of the quantities $s$ and $p$, respectively ($\mathbb{E}[\tilde{s}_n]=s$ and $\mathbb{E}[\tilde{p}_n]=p$). Imagine we have obtained asymptotic bounds for the errors of these estimators (e.g., using Chebyshev inequality or Chernoff bounds):
$$|\tilde{s}_n-s|\leq\mathcal{O}_p(a_n),$$
$$|\tilde{p}_n-p|\leq\mathcal{O}_p(b_n).$$

For example, see [page 2](http://www.gautamkamath.com/CS860notes/lec3.pdf).

How can we use the bounds of the errors of the estimators to bound the error of operations of the estimators: e.g.,  $\frac{\tilde{s}_n}{\tilde{p}_n}$ in estimating $\frac{s}{p}$ or  $\tilde{s}_n\, \tilde{p}_n$ in estimating $s\, p$?

Comment: Well, given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N,C$ so that if $n \geq N$ then $|\tilde{s}_n-s| \leq Ca_n$ and $|\tilde{p}_n-p| \leq Cb_n$ both hold simultaneously with probability at least $1-\varepsilon$. From there you can do interval arithmetic; for example, $\tilde{p}_n \tilde{s}_n$ will now be between $(s-Ca_n)(p-Cb_n)$ and $(s+Ca_n)(p+Cb_n)$ (assuming for simplicity that $p,s$ have the same sign) with probability at least $1-\varepsilon$. That means $|\tilde{s}_n \tilde{p}_n - sp| \leq \mathcal{O}_p(a_n+b_n+a_n b_n)$.

Comment: A serious limitation of this approach especially when you are propagating a lot of errors is that when you have a lot of errors they tend to cancel out, whereas this method is assuming that they actually compound one another. Fixing that requires you to know something about the joint distribution.

Comment: Thanks, @Ian! That's very helpful. I'm interested in the case where $s_n$ and $p_n$ are not independent. Could you give a bit more detail on how to use the joint distribution to have a tighter bound? Thank you.

Comment: Well, consider the product case for example. Given a fixed point $(x_0,y_0)$ with both coordinates positive and $\varepsilon<x_0 y_0$, the set $\{ (x,y) : x_0  y_0 -\varepsilon \leq xy \leq x_0 y_0+\varepsilon \}$ is a whole strip in the plane, consisting of $y$ between $\frac{x_0 y_0+\varepsilon}{x}$ and $\frac{x_0 y_0-\varepsilon}{x}$ where $x$ can be anything positive. The goal is to estimate the overall probability of that entire strip. You can see how this isn't solely related to the marginal distributions.